# Menu item won't change title

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

Main Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var optionsMenu: Menu? = null

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu)
        optionsMenu = menu
        Log.e("Options Menu", "Menu initialized")

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    private fun switchToNightMode() {
        SharedVars.nightMode = true
        val btnNightMode =  optionsMenu?.findItem(R.id.btnNightMode)
        btnNightMode?.title = "Light Mode"
    }
}
```

I made sure that the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called based by a log before.
Why isn't it changing when I call the `switchToNightMode` function?

Comment: Probably `btnNightMode` is null?

Comment: how is it null?, but if it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: Plus, i just ran a null check with a log, and it returned not null

Comment: Normally it shouldn't be null unless the `btnNightMode` id doesn't exist in `R.menu.navigation_menu`

Comment: Well, now that it isn't null, what should I do?

Comment: Try `getItem()` instead of `findItem`, it takes in the order instead

Comment: Also try to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` after setting the title

Comment: Nope, doesn't work I've added `invalidateOptionsMenu` and `getItem`